# Is there a assembly tester?

Tags: assembly, disassembly

I mean something like a regular expression tester.

I could input the machine code and the software could verify/disassemble it to see whether the code is correct/what does the code represent.

I could also input the assembly and the software could also verify/assemble it to machine code.

It should have a GUI interface and run under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

gcc or gnu assembler (as) will assemble the code for syntax, very quick to check.  then objdump to disassemble if you want to see the opcodes or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

This is probabbly a little late, but I use the program EMU8086 which gives you a nice editor with colour coding, then you click the run button, it brings up a cool emulator with a simple dos like screen, and you can run your program. You can step forward, line by line, and even step back. Its sooo cool and really aids my learning of assembly.

The only problem with this program is that the syntax in some places, is slightly different than MASM true assembly. Also it ONLY supports 8086/8088 instruction set. No good if you want to use 286 and above for example, so forget doing windows assembly in it.

It is a windows program however, its small, and incredibly easy to use and learn from. Super cool if you are learning from old books on assembly as it will run most listings without a hitch.

Enjoy learning assembler, hope this was useful. Dont give up on it as it can be a challenge but it is worth the effort. Over the next 6 months or so I will be writing a proper assembly tutorial that will be easy to understand. So dont give up.

Just as a query though, since you are now doing assembly longer than me, could you pop over to try and answer my question, or even offer suggestions on where to look. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[OllyDbg](http://ollydbg.de/) has a disassmbler and assembler. And also aalows you to edit bytes (machine code). And it's free.

Comment: I believe of all the tools of this kind it's the simplest. The disassembler is shown after you load executable. To assemble some code you just start typing in CPU window. To edit bytes you press Ctrl-E.

Comment: OllyDbg definitely is the best choice for what you want